# Error "Invalid utf8 character string" while upgrading MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have some InnoDB databases on my local MacBook Pro. And after upgrading MySQL through `brew upgrade` MySQL daemon can't start now.

I already fixed problems with new case insensitive mode by renaming appropriate tables in filesystem.

But there is still error `Invalid utf8 character string` that I don't know how to fix.

```
2019-11-29T10:55:32.147554Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 36384
2019-11-29T10:55:32.152566Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-11-29T10:55:32.166564Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2019-11-29T10:55:36.248838Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Invalid utf8 character string: '8AAEAB'
2019-11-29T10:55:36.253228Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Invalid utf8 character string: '84A5A9'
2019-11-29T10:55:36.254541Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Invalid utf8 character string: '92A8AF'
2019-11-29T10:55:36.273197Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Invalid utf8 character string: '8CAEAB'
2019-11-29T10:55:38.424116Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2019-11-29T10:55:38.424785Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-11-29T10:55:39.484843Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  Homebrew.
```

I don't know in what table I have these characters. And I can't find any character that can be encoded by these 3-bytes strings.

Comment: Is there an option to change the Collation on the instance?

Comment: I tried put it in the `my.cnf` but problem is still here

Comment: What exactly did you put in your .cnf around Collation?

Comment: `character-set-server=utf8mb4`

Comment: try `collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: There is a known [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93101) if you're upgrading from tables that have pre MySQL 5.6.4 date columns. You haven't provided much information (e.g. you're running, what you tried to upgrade to and so on).